# Subprocess call function

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, terminate

I want to use   [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for calling somme commands and this is example for start ans stop a subprocess :

```
import subprocess  
# Start
proc = subprocess.Popen(command)  
# Stop
proc.terminate()
```

But Now am trying to define a seprated functions for doing that process wich sould be like :

```
import os,sys
import subprocess
class Process:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = None
    def start(self,cmd):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

    def stop(self):
        self.proc.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = "XXXXX"
    p =Process()
    p.start(cmd)
    p.stop()
```

It works and it launch the process start but it still alive and can not call the stop function even with killing the process with pid.

Is there is a way to stop the process through calling the stop function ?

Comment: Youre not returning `proc` from `start`.

Comment: i call the start function in the main

Comment: The `start` will work but there is no way you will terminate `proc` since you don't save the variable anywhere. What are you passing as an argument to `stop`?

Comment: Yes the proc is a global variable ..I define it into the init function to the class .. which should be known inside the stop function ?

Comment: In the code you posted there are no `class` or global variables. Please update your question to include the code you are using.

Comment: Ok Code updated

Comment: The class methods need `self` as first argument, and if you want to change the attribute of `Process`, you would use `self.proc` instead. In this case, `stop` will not need `proc` as argument.

Comment: Like that :  ```import os,sys
import subprocess
import signal

class Process:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = None
    def start(self,cmd):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd) 

    def stop(self):
        self.proc.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = "xxxxxxxx"
    p =Process()
    p.start(cmd)
    p.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the variable `proc` is local to the function `start`, so it doesn't exist outside it. You can try returning the variable like this:

```
def start(cmd):
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd) 

def stop(proc):
    proc.terminate()

cmd= #your command
proc = start(cmd)
stop(proc)
```

Comment: This is what am trying to do ..but the process still alive ..can not be stopped or killed